# What is the global complex moduli space for dimensions higher than 1?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, moduli-space, mirror-symmetry

I am trying to read the book 'Mirror Symmetry and Algebraic Geometry' by D. Cox and S. Katz. In the book it claims that 'the space of all complex structures on a given manifold $V$ is a well known object in algebraic geometry'. Although I have seen a (very) little bit of deformation theory, I am unfamiliar with thinking about global moduli spaces. I also saw that for *curves*, there is a very nice moduli stack $\mathcal{M}_{g,n}$ that is in a definite sense a global moduli space, which solves a well-defined moduli problem. But I could not find any accesible references to global moduli spaces for dimensions $\geq2$. Also it is claimed that the full complex moduli space of a Calabi-Yau manifold $V$ is a smooth manifold, but the references also had only local statements.

So what exactly is this moduli space, and in what sense is it a moduli space?

Comment: Did you try the book Sundararaman, D., "Moduli, deformations and classifications of compact complex manifolds"? However, it is a bit dated and does not include a discussion of CY manifolds.

Comment: Basically, the theory has only been worked out satisfactorily in dimension $1$. Even in the case of surfaces, I'm not sure enough is known for it to make sense for someone to write the kind of reference you're looking for.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thank you, that was what I suspected after searching. So does that mean I should think of the 'moduli' discussed in mirror symmetry in the context of deformation theory? Also, is there a simple explanation for why the higher dimensional case is much harder than curves?

Comment: It's not that *nothing* is known in higher dimensions, but the results are scattered (and often restricted to special cases). That said, deformation theory is nothing but the local study of moduli spaces. As for why higher dimensions are harder...well, for starters a given curve has a unique smooth, proper birational model (you "pull apart" any singular points and then fill in any holes). Starting in dimension 2, you have an infinitude of smooth, projective varieties which are mutually non-isomorphic but birational (just keep blowing up points)...

Comment: ...There is also the matter of stability (in the sense of GIT). Stability for curves is combinatorial; you need (1) any singularities to be nodes, and (2) the genus and/or number of marked points to be large enough to kill off any infinitesimal automorphisms. I don't believe any straightforward description exists once you leave dimension $1$.

Comment: Smoothness is a local property, so the smoothness of the moduli space being established through local arguments isn't a problem. However, I would refer you to this book: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-19004-9 It contains an extensive discussion of the deformation theory, and the Bogomolov-Tian-Todorov theorem (i.e. smoothness of the moduli space).

Comment: @QuaereVerum thank you, that looks like a really nice reference!

Comment: I am not sure if there are any references giving the following (analytic) line of thought: consider the space of almost complex structures on an even dimensional manifold and then cut out the complex structures via Newlander-Nirenberg.

Comment: @CraniumClamp I think this approach is taken in Huybrecht's *Complex Geometry, An Introduction*, Chapter 6, and leads to the Maurer-Cartan equation (though imo [Huybrechts is missing a factor of $2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4168781/maurer-cartan-integrability-condition-of-an-almost-complex-structure)).